# How to cancel the "Keep your account secure" process during login in the Azur portal?

Tags: azure, portal

I use a desktop computer and don't have a smartphone (and have no plans to buy one). Because of this, I am unable to implement the "Secure Your Account" process during login in the Azure portal.

Our administrator has disabled multi-factor authentication for my account. But after 14 days the "Secure Your Account" appeared again during login in the Azure portal.

Comment: Check this- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-admin-center/disable-quot-keep-your-account-secure-quot/m-p/2038998 and Inform your administrator about the reoccurrence of the prompt. They might need to review the Azure AD security settings again. Your administrator should review any Conditional Access policies in Azure Active Directory (AD) that might be enforcing additional security measures. Administrators can check Azure AD sign-in logs to understand why the prompt is being triggered.

Comment: It seems like you've already bought a smartphone, and this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To cancel the "Keep your account secure" process during login in the Azure portal without a smartphone, you will need to work with your Azure administrator. They have the capability to modify security settings and disable features like multi-factor authentication (MFA) that prompt this process. If MFA has been disabled but you're still getting the prompt, it's possible that there are residual settings or policies in place that need to be adjusted by the administrator. Communicate with your Azure administrator to address this issue.

There are other alternatives other than using smartphone.

1. You can use security token devices like [Yubi key](https://zapier.com/blog/what-is-a-yubikey/)
2. You can setup [RSA Token](https://www.rsa.com/products/securid/) on your laptop
3. if you have a basic feature phone, you can get your token in form of [SMS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/set-up-text-messaging-as-your-verification-method-a61dcc0c-a003-424f-8a64-d92534ba0dad) or [phonecall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/set-up-a-phone-call-as-your-verification-method-e54d955d-ac82-4741-91e3-dae6c8bb9d98) via [MS authenticator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/download-and-install-the-microsoft-authenticator-app-351498fc-850a-45da-b7b6-27e523b8702a)

By the way, I would request you or your admin to check
the below-
visit Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Multi-Factor Authentication, your accounts -> check "Multi-Factor Auth Status" as "Disabled",
[image]

If this is disabled, still you are getting the prompt then final option is to try this:

1. Go to [https://portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com/)
2. Use the search bar on the upper middle part of the page and search of "Azure Active Directory".
3. Under Azure Active Directory, search for Properties on the left-hand panel. It is in-between of User Settings and Security.
4. Under the Properties, click on Manage Security defaults.
5. Under the Enable Security defaults, toggle it to NO.
6. Wait for few minutes for propagation then try to sign-in using InPrivate or Incognito.

[image]

This is not recommended. But if your admin allows, then good for you.

Comment: Dear Arko,
I am very grateful to you for your detailed explanations on how to solve my problem!